# Netbeans disable some format

Tags: php, netbeans

In Netbeans 8.0, open Tools >> Options menu.

Open Editor >> Formatting tab.

Where, PHP Language has Spaces Category.

If I tick option "Around Operators" >> "Assignment Operators" checkbox, it gives 1 space around "=" (equals to sign). 
If I uncheck above checkbox, it gives 0 space around "=" (equals to sign).

What if I want same space as I want around "=" (equals to sign)? (Not 1 and not 0 space, but exactly the spaces I have given).

For example,

```
    $rateQtyId = $latestTradeInsertId;
    $rateQty   = $pRow2['realQty']; //we want to write same qty as realQty
    $rateDate  = $rateDate;
    $parity    = $parity;
```

I want spaces I have exactly what I have given instead of 1 or 0 spaces around "=" (equals to sign).

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans, open Tools >> Options menu.

Open Editor >> Formatting tab.

Select PHP as Language and Alignment as Category.

Check Assignment under Group and Multiline Alignment.

Apply then OK.

And start using format as desired.

Comment: Ok, this has solved my problem partially. What if I have = & += both assignment and both I want vertically at same position ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible in netbeans at this time.

Comment: I do not want automatically, but at least netbeans should allow what I format (Netbeans should not change what I have formatted).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your 1st answer. It has helped me (If I did not got that answer, I was about to stop using auto format in netbeans!).